# How do I read values in a Material 2 table?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have an Angular 2 app that uses a [Material 2 table](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview) to display items and their data. I have a button on the right of each row that allows the user to edit that row. This toggle edit button causes `input`s to pop up, populated with the values of that row. The value of the input is set using `value="{{row.property}}"`.

I could use [(ngModel)]="row.property" to populate the `input`'s value and have the model bound to that object, but I don't want that because I want the user to be able to cancel making changes. If the `input` is bound to the object, the model will change even if the user clicks "Cancel".

So, setting `value="{{row.property}}"` is what I want, but I don't know how to retrieve the values of the `input`s when I click the "Save" button.

```html
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>

  <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
        The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->

  <!-- Season Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="season">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="padding-a-5" mat-sort-header> Season </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" class="padding-a-5">
      <span *ngIf="!editingRow(row)"> {{row.season}} </span>
      <input *ngIf="editingRow(row)" value="{{row.season}}" class="padding-a-5 half-width">
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Item Name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="mat-column-itemName padding-a-5" mat-sort-header> Item Name </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" class="mat-column-itemName">
      <span *ngIf="!editingRow(row)"> {{row.name}} </span>
      <input *ngIf="editingRow(row)" [(ngModel)]="row.name" class="padding-a-5 half-width">
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Toggle Edit Row Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="toggleEdit">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="mat-column-row-actions"></mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" class="toggle-edit mat-column-row-actions">
      <button *ngIf="!editingRow(row)" mat-button (click)="editRow(row, true)" aria-label="edit">
        <mat-icon aria-hidden="true">mode_edit</mat-icon>
      </button>

      <button *ngIf="editingRow(row)" mat-button (click)="saveRow(row)" aria-label="save">
        <mat-icon aria-hidden="true">save</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <button *ngIf="editingRow(row)" mat-button (click)="editRow(row, false)" aria-label="cancel">
        <mat-icon aria-hidden="true">cancel</mat-icon>
      </button>
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
```

```js
  // some of the methods in my Angular 2 component
  
  editingRow(row) {
    return this.editRows[row.id];
  }

  editRow(row, editRow: boolean) {
    this.toggleEditMode(row.id, editRow);
  }

  saveRow(row): void {
    this.toggleEditMode(row.id, false);
    console.log(row);
    // TODO
    // save(row);
  }

  toggleEditMode(rowId: number, editMode: boolean): void {
    this.editRows[rowId] = editMode;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

On edit, store the existing state of the object, then if they cancel, set it back to the original

```
public function edit(item: YourClass) {
    this.OriginalItem = item;
    this.isEditing = true;
}

public function cancel(index: number) {
   this.MyListOfItems[index] = this.OriginalItem;
   this.isEditing = false;
}
```

Comment: Good idea, and I thought about that, but won't that just copy the object reference to that array? Then any changes made to the original would also be made to the object in the "memory" array.

Comment: I just looked at a place where I do that. I use `angular.copy(object)` to make it work. So yes, you're correct :D